# Padding zeroes to left of string (python)?

Tags: python

The length of the string needs to be 5 characters. When the string is "1" it needs to be returned as "00001", when the string is "10" it needs to be returned as "00010" and so on. I'm wondering how to do this using loops?

Comment: Have you thought using some of the `str` method. The docs have some really good examples and they provide lots of insight.

Comment: Such as [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) and its [spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Comment: `'{:0>5}'.format(string)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use for-loops, you can solve the problem like so:

```
def addPadding(str):
    output = ''
    # Prepend output with 0s
    for i in range(5 - len(str)):
        output += '0'
    output += str
    return output

print(addPadding('10'))
>> 00010
print(addPadding('1'))
>> 00001
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use string formatting or arrays or anything besides integer operators, you should be able to figure it out using division and a loop.

Is 10 divisible by 10000?
Is 10 divisible by 1000?
Is 10 divisible by 100?
etc.

Try typing 10/10000 in your python interpreter.  What's the result? :)